# How to display input field in Spring MVC list

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo, jspx

In my Spring Roo project, I have generated an 'Event' domain object, with MVC controllers and views.

I would like to have a feature where the events (which are all string values) are all encrypted and authorised users who have the corresponding key can obtain the decrypted event information.

Currently, when the user presses the "List all events" button, a list of all the events are displayed (all encrypted string values).

I need to add an input field next to each of the events displayed in the event list (list.jspx) where the user enters his key. The controller will then use the input key value to decrypt and display the decrypted event information (in show.jspx).

In the list.jspx file, I added:

```
<form:create id="fl_au_edu_usyd_latte_experience_domain_Event" modelAttribute="event" path="/events" render="${empty dependencies}" z="">
<field:input path="partialKey" id="l_au_edu_usyd_latte_experience_domain_Event_partialKey"/>
</form:create>
```

In the EventController_Roo_Controller.aj file, I added:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", produces = "text/html")
public String EventController.show(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model uiModel, String partialKey) {
    addDateTimeFormatPatterns(uiModel);
    uiModel.addAttribute("partialKey", partial_key);


    uiModel.addAttribute("event", Event.findEvent(id));
    uiModel.addAttribute("itemId", id);
    return "events/show";
}
```

However, when I run the project I get the error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/views/events/list.jspx(12,146) The prefix "form" for element "form:create" is not bound.
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is due to that you have not configured the prefix of the response file. you need to configure a `viewresolver` in `springmvc-servlet.xml`:

```
<bean id="viewresolver"  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: The viewresolver seems to be set up correctly. The form shows up correctly in create.jspx file but not in the list.jspx file (both are within the same directory)

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have the `WEB-INF/tags` folder which Roo would install in your project. i.e there is no form in the tags folder in your WEB-INF. Please double check it

Comment: Adding the taglib gives me this error:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/views/events/list.jspx(1,2) The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.

Comment: I already have this code which was generated for me by Spring Roo near the top of the page:
<div xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:page="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/form" xmlns:table="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/form/fields" version="2.0">

Comment: I've checked the folder and all the tags are there. The forms show up in the create.jspx, but not in the list.jspx file for some reason. Both are in the same directory.